# Change color of an item in ListView with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I'm populating a ListView using a SimpleAdapter

```
ArrayList<Recipe> ciboList = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

    for(int i=0;i<ciboList.size();i++){
        // Recipe is my own class defined in another java
        Recipe r = (Recipe) ciboList.get(i);

        HashMap<String,Object> ricettaMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        // Informations loaded from Recipe.java
        ricettaMap.put("tipo", r.getTipo());
        ricettaMap.put("titolo", r.getTitolo());
        ricettaMap.put("difficolta", r.getDifficolta());
        ricettaMap.put("tempo", r.getTempo());
        ricettaMap.put("persone", r.getPersone());
        ricettaMap.put("ingredienti", r.getIngredienti());
        ricettaMap.put("vino", r.getVino());
        ricettaMap.put("consigli", r.getConsigli());
        ricettaMap.put("preparazione", r.getPreparazione());            

        }        
    }

    String[] from = {"tipo", "titolo", "difficolta", "tempo", "ingredienti", "vino", "consigli", "preparazione", "persone"};
    int[] to = {R.id.ricettaTipo, R.id.ricettaTitolo, R.id.ricettaDifficolta, R.id.ricettaTempo, R.id.ricettaIngredienti, R.id.ricettaVino, R.id.ricettaConsigli, R.id.ricettaPrep, R.id.ricettaPersone};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            data,
            R.layout.list_cibo,
            from,
            to);
```

XML of R.layout.list_cibo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:padding="5dip"
android:gravity="right">
<TextView
    android:text="Titolo Ricetta"
    android:singleLine="true"       
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:id="@+id/ricettaTitolo">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:text="Difficoltà"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ricettaDifficolta"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:text="Tempo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ricettaDifficolta"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#FF3300" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ricettaDifficolta"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/ricettaTempo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ricettaTipo"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ricettaPersone"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ricettaIngredienti">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ricettaVino">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ricettaConsigli"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ricettaPrep"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

I use three different SimpleAdapter to create three different lists, based on three different colors; what I'd like to do is to create only one list that colors each item in one of the three colors, according to a parameter.

I've tried modifying the TextViews using    `.setColor` but it doesn't work.

Comment: post the code of how you are setting the color.

Comment: The code is set in the SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter declaration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a method inside `SimpleAdapter` for that. It's called `ViewBinder`. Try to include this line of code immediately after:
 `SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.list_cibo, from, to);”` and before `“setListAdapter(adapter);`.

```
SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object object, String value) {
System.out.println("view= "+view);
    System.out.println("view.toString()= "+ view.toString());
    System.out.println("view.getId()= "+ view.getId());
    System.out.println("view.getVisibility()= "+ view.getVisibility());
    System.out.println("view.equals((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id. ricettaTipo))= "+ view.equals((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id. ricettaTipo)));
    if (view.equals((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ricettaTipo)))
            {
                TextView ricetta = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ricettaTipo);
                    //Change color/answer/etc for ricettaTipo
            }

//OR
          if (view instanceof TextView) {
                    //Do stuff
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
            };
adapter.setViewBinder(binder);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

`setViewValue` method will be called for each `R.id.ricettaTipo, R.id.ricettaTitolo, R.id.ricettaDifficolta, R.id.ricettaTempo, R.id.ricettaIngredienti, R.id.ricettaVino, R.id.ricettaConsigli, R.id.ricettaPrep, R.id.ricettaPersone.` `The setViewValue` method will be called each View/each time one of the above `R.id’s` is being drawn.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since this answer is more relevant to the question and it really saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try extending the SimpleAdapter class with a custom adapter class, maybe recipe adapter, and overwrite the getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) Method.

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
        }

        private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent, int resource) {
            View v;
            if (convertView == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
                /* set a background color depending on the recipe shown in this table 
                 * row you will have to include a recipe.getType() method 
                 * to determine the necessary color
                 * v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.your_favourite_color)
                 */        

                final int[] to = mTo;
                final int count = to.length;
                final View[] holder = new View[count];

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    holder[i] = v.findViewById(to[i]);
                }

                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                v = convertView;
            }

            bindView(position, v);

            return v;
        }
```

the code is taken from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java#SimpleAdapter.getView%28int,android.view.View,android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, let me know if I got it right: I create a new Class defining my SimpleAdapter, then I override the View of the existing Class using the one I defined?